# Save the screenshot of a widget

Tags: qt, qwidget

I want to save a screenshot of a widget in Qt.
I created the following code that should work:

```
  QWidget* activeWidget = getActiveWidget();//a function that returns the current widget.
  if (activeWidget == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  QPixmap screenshot;
  screenshot = QPixmap::grabWidget(activeWidget,activeWidget->rect());
  if(screenshot.isNull()){
    printf("ERROR");
  }
 bool a= screenshot.save("c:\\temp\\asd.jpg", "JPG", 50);
```

But unfortunately this does not seem to work. 
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: does it print "ERROR"(your printf..) ?

Comment: A bunch of things could be happening, the code you provided here has no apparent problems. Are there any overridden `paintEvent()` functions and where are you calling this from? Does `grabWindow()` work?

Comment: What is the value of boolean variable 'a' after the .save is called ? And are you sure your code is executed ? Are you calling it on a button press or timer ? Verify by putting a printf and printing the value of 'a'.

Comment: hey..
i am not overiding paintEvent().
the error print is not printed.
and a is false.and the code for sure is executed.

Comment: Well there you have it, the pixmap saving part is broken. `save()` should return `true` upon success. The save itself, however, seems correct. Does the directory exist and do you have write permissions?

Comment: yes, it exists and i have writing pr omission.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142502/saving-qpixmap-to-jpeg-failing-qt-4-5#1142555) and [this forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25920-QPixmap-save()-doesn-t-work), people suggest the following:

Most likely, the plugin which is required to handle .jpg files is not found by your application. In order to resolve this issue, do one of the following things:

- If you are doing a static build, add `QTPLUGIN += qjpeg` to your .pro file or
- if you are doing a dynamic build, put the `imageformats` folder from `%QTDIR%\plugins` next to your .exe